# How do I fix "error: error in setup.cfg: command 'bdist_wheel' has no such option 'universal'"

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

When doing `python setup.py bdist_wheel` I got an error:

`error: error in setup.cfg: command 'bdist_wheel' has no such option 'universal'`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my `wheel` package was out of date (v0.22 isn't new enough).  A quick `pip install --upgrade wheel` and it built happily.

Before I figured that out, though, I'd spent a fruitless half hour upgrading `pip` and `setuptools` and `python-distutils-extra`.